# Which word should I use for "to drive (a car)"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I've seen several verbs: *konduki, stiri, veturigi*. I've thought of *aŭti* too, and I just saw that ReVo actually suggests it.

Which one is the best? Do they fit in different situations?

Comment: And remember, in English we park on the driveway and drive on the parkway:)

Comment: @MikeJones Really?

Comment: Yes, indeed: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/drive-parkway-park-driveway-history

Comment: @MikeJones haha, interesa artikolo

Answer (score 11):

To this list we can add ***ŝofori***.

I've been asking myself this same question for close to 20 years and I've come to the conclusion that there is no obvious **best answer**. Each one at times seems to not quite to fit, and I notice that people tend to pick based on a number of factors, including the word that their Esperanto teacher used as well as national language bias.

Personally I say *ŝofori*, the disadvantage of which is that to at least some speakers this carries the extra nuance of "driving someone else around."

And yes, the suitability of some of the options does vary a bit by context.

***konduki*** - This is a general word meaning "to lead." It can be used to mean drive a car.

***stiri*** - Although sometimes used to mean "drive (a car, boat, airplane, etc), the meaning of the word *stirilo* very clearly is limited in sense to the actual steering. When someone uses *stiri* with the sense "to drive", I know what they mean, but in the back of my mind I'm wondering who is pushing the pedals.

***veturigi*** - This has two meanings. To drive (a vehicle) and to transport (by vehicle). It's a good choice, but sometimes clumsy in compound words.

***aŭti*** - This means "to go by car" and would not be used with an object. It also doesn't tell you who is actually driving.

***ŝofori*** - This is my choice for the best general word for "to drive." It's true that PIV defines this as *Labori kiel ŝoforo*, but for various reasons, this is my preferred choice. I note that this is the word Claude Piron used in *Gerda Malaperis*, and that was a big influence on me when I was first learning.

Answer (score 7):

The English verb *to drive* is an example of an English word that has multiple closely related usages/meanings, which should however be kept separate when translating the word to other languages (not only Esperanto).

One can use *to drive* with a vehicle as object, meaning 'to cause and guide the movement of (the vehicle)', as in "He is driving an old car". For this you should use *konduki*, *veturigi* or *stiri*, and certainly not *aŭti* or *veturi*. Here are the differences between the three words:

- *veturigi* with an vehicle as object is a perfect equivalent of 'to drive' with a vehicle as object.
- *stiri* literally means 'to steer', but it is often used in a *pars pro toto* way to mean 'to drive'.
- *konduki*  can also be used for other things than vehicles (it just means 'to lead'), but when used with a vehicle, its meaning becomes identical to *veturigi*.

It is a question of style and personal preference to choose between these three words.

One can also use *to drive* with a transported person or thing as object, meaning 'to convey (the person or thing) in a vehicle', as in "I will drive you home". This is *veturigi* in Esperanto, and *konduki*, *stiri*, *aŭti* and *veturi* are wrong in this meaning.

Finally, *to drive* can also be used without an object, meaning 'to go or travel in a driven vehicle', as in "I drove to L.A. by myself". For this you can use *veturi* or *aŭti*. The latter one is more precise, as it explicitly mentions the kind of vehicle that was used.

Additionally, there is the word *ŝofori*, which derives from *ŝoforo*, a driver by profession. Given that it is derived from *ŝoforo*, many people understand it to convey a meaning of working as a driver or driving people or things around in a similar way as someone who works as a driver. Others however use the word just as a synonym of 'to drive', without any additional idea of profession-like driving.

Another doubt related to *ŝofori* is what it can take as object: What is clear is that it can be used both in an intransitive way (without object), or with the vehicle as an object. Some people additionally use it with a transported person or thing as object, while others consider this wrong.

I personally think that it is OK to use *ŝofori* with a transported person or thing as object, but that the word should only be used when one actually wants to convey a meaning of of profession-like driving, in line with the meaning of the word *ŝoforo*, from which it derives. It seems to me that the usage of *ŝofori* without the idea of profession-like driving only spread because some people had difficulties distinguishing the different meaning of 'to drive', and wanted a word that they can use as a translation of 'to drive' in all contexts. Instead of taking this "easy" solution that goes against the core meaning of the word root *ŝofor/*, one should learn to distinguish the different uses of 'to drive', and to translate them accordingly. If one just sticks to *veturigi* and *veturi*, it is not really that difficult: You just use *veturigi* whenever *to drive* has an object (no matter whether it is the vehicle or a person/thing that is being transported), and *veturi* whenever *to drive* doesn't have an object.