# Car and driving vocabulary

Tags: translation, questions

Does anyone have a list of the different parts of a car (inside outside, e.g. windshield, trunk, steering wheel, gear) along with their Esperanto words?

Similarly, any vocabulary list relating to driving? (e.g. Traffic, traffic light, pedestrian crossing, road sign)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite exactly the same, a similar question has been asked here: [Which word should I use for "to drive (a car)"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2048/which-word-should-i-use-for-to-drive-a-car)

Individual vocabulary items should be easily findable in any good bilingual dictionary. For a list, I would suggest one of the picture dictionaries. For example, the Esperanta Bildvortaro, which is findable in PDF form in various places online. Here is one link.

https://www.pdf-archive.com/2012/02/05/esperanta-bildvortaro-rudiger-eichholz/

The pictures related to cars are numbers 185 and 186.

Answer (score 1):

Revo is a good source for that type of information: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/inx/fx_TRA.html

Comment: This doesn't *really* provide an answer to the question